# How do I Make an Excel worksheet scroll to a row programatically

Tags: c#, vsto, excel-2010

I have a VSTO add-in for Excel that populates a listobject in a worksheet with data, and I would like to the sheet to automatically scroll to show the bottom of the list (without forcing focus onto this sheet if the user is looking at another). Is there a way to do this programmatically?

Thanks <333

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
Worksheet worksheet = Application.Sheets[2]; //Index of the sheet you want to change the selected cell on

if (worksheet == Application.ActiveSheet)
{
    Excel.Range range = worksheet.UsedRange;

    int rows = range.Rows.Count;
    int columns = range.Columns.Count;

    Excel.Range activeCell = worksheet.Cells[rows, columns];
    activeCell.Select();
}
```

Simply select the sheet with your data, check to see if this is the sheet the user is currently working with and if so create a Range object equal to the used cells of the sheet, and then get a count of the columns and rows, and create a second Range object equal to the bottom-right used cell, and call the `Select();` method on this Range to make it the active cell.

Comment: Yep, that works a treat! This will go in an event handler on SheetSelectionChange as well as in my refresh logic.

Comment: I don't think that is quite correct. **activeCell.Select()** will simply **select** the cell even if it is not in view. The correct way to do this is to use something like: **Application.ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = range.Rows.Count**.

Comment: @BenStabile you should add your comment as an answer which is the correct answer.

Comment: Works perfectly for Excel 2010 in my case. With scrolling and everything even the column will be scrolled, if outside the visible range

Answer (score 5):

NOTE: This answer is taken from **Ben Stabile**'s comment under the accepted answer; just in case other people are looking for a '**correct**' answer but didn't happen to see the comment.
I tried what Ben suggested and it achieves exactly what "Go To" in Excel does.

`activeCell.Select()` will simply select the cell even if it is not in view. The correct way to do this is to use something like: `Application.ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = range.Rows.Count.`

Comment: Just to say that the accepted answer is wrong, this is the right answer.

Comment: Just to say, the accepted answer works perfectly for Excel 2010 in my case. With scrolling and everything even the column will be scrolled which is not handled by this answer. With respect: no, this is not the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

// Code for "Split", "freeze", "adding filter", "column auto fit" for all sheets in the workbook

```
 //path were excel file is kept
            string ResultsFilePath = @"C:\\Users\\krakhil\\Desktop\\FolderName\\FileNameWithoutExtension";

            Excel.Application ExcelApp = new Excel.Application();
            Excel.Workbook ExcelWorkbook = ExcelApp.Workbooks.Open(ResultsFilePath);
            ExcelApp.Visible = true;

            //Looping through all available sheets
            foreach (Excel.Worksheet ExcelWorksheet in ExcelWorkbook.Sheets)
            {                
                //Selecting the worksheet where we want to perform action
                ExcelWorksheet.Select(Type.Missing);

                //Making sure first row is selected - else split and freeze will happen
                //On the visible part and not from the top
                Excel.Range activeCell = ExcelWorksheet.Cells[1, 1];
                activeCell.Select();

                //Applying auto filter to Row 10
                activeCell = (Excel.Range)ExcelWorksheet.Rows[10];
                activeCell.AutoFilter(1,
                    Type.Missing,
                    Excel.XlAutoFilterOperator.xlAnd,
                    Type.Missing,
                    true);

                //Split the pane and freeze it
                ExcelWorksheet.Application.ActiveWindow.SplitRow = 10;
                ExcelWorksheet.Application.ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = true;

                //Auto fit all columns
                ExcelWorksheet.Columns.AutoFit();

                //Releasing range object
                Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(activeCell);
            }

            //saving excel file using Interop
            ExcelWorkbook.Save();

            //closing file and releasing resources
            ExcelWorkbook.Close(Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
            Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(ExcelWorkbook);
            ExcelApp.Quit();
            Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(ExcelApp);
```